# How can I click a button inside a frame with selenium webdriver in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, selenium-webdriver, vba, frame

I made an automation for a webpage which has frames, and I need to click on several menu links before returning to the maincontent to complete the tasks. This automation is run from Access-VBA. Here is a fragment of the HTML that shows the frame:

```html
<frameset id="topFrameset"> 
  <frameset id="BodyFrameset" cols="0,177,*">
    <frame name="ButtonsFrame" id="ButtonsFrame" target="main" scrolling="NO" noresize="" src="MyMenu.action">
      #document
      <html>
      <body>
        <input type="hidden" name="listParentsId" value="[501, 502, 503]" id="listParentsId">
        <div id="menu_container">
          <div id="menu_1" onmouseover="MENU.ToolTipsCreate('501')">
            <a onclick="MENU.showItems('501', '')">My Account</a>
            <img id="img_501" src="/common/images/dropdown2_arrow.png" onclick="MENU.showItems('501', '')">
          </div>
        </div>  
      </body></html>
    </frame>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

I am using the [SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases) bindings for VBA. See [Browser automation in Excel VBA using Selenium](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) for install and tutorial.

I've tried webdriver.SwitchToFrame, among many other tests, all of them failed.

```
Dim driver As selenium.WebDriver
Set driver = New ChromeDriver
driver.Get (URL)

'Here goes the part of the code that logs in the page, it's irrelevant for this analysis...

driver.SwitchToFrame ("topFrameset") 'This line returns Error N°: 8 - NoSuchFrameError. Frame not be found. Identifier:topFrameset
```

Hope that someone could guide me to click the link or the img element inside "menu_1". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ page, I can't find any COM/VBA bindings for WebDriver. How are you using this in Access? Are you using the C# driver? If so, how? Are you possibly trying to use the Selenium2Excel Converter?

Comment: Possibly this? https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases
  Tutorial? https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/
  If so, please give complete code sample where you setup the WebDriver, and try to interact with the HTML

Comment: That's right. I downloaded Selenium from https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases The tutorial page you mention is quite helpful too. To use it from Access VBA, you must go to the coding window (alt + F11) and then Tools - References and then search "Selenium Type Library" and tick it. I hope that helps you. Unfortunately, there isn't much help for Selenium in VBA, instead there is a lot for Java (which I don't know at all). And also Selenium offer more tools for that language.

Comment: OK, good. Please check out Anand's answer. If that doesn't help, please provide a complete code sample for your sample HTML. Also, explain further what you mean by 'None of them worked'. Did you get an error? A wrong response? No response?

Answer (score 0):

In 'EXAMPLE TEST 2', Can you comment this line `driver.SwitchToDefaultContent`and try it?
Why you switch to defaultcontent before switching to frame?

defaultContent –> Switch back to default page

Try other options as well: (In JAVA, we do.)

`switchTo().frame(int) – Switch to a frame with its index
switchTo().frame(“name of the frame”) – Switch to a frame with its name
switchTo().frame (WebElement) – Switch to a frame with its web element location`

Comment: In fact I did it. It was not my first try, but searching the web I found I site where someone recommended to switch to default content before going inside a frame. But it didn't work either. I did many attempts, but I didn't want the explanation to be so long.

Comment: I also found many places like your comments, where they refer to "WebElement". What is selenium expecting to receive as a WebElement? I am asking you because I tried many times to declare a WebElement and use it but I didn't figure out how to do it. I am locating many thing by Id, name, XPath and by Css, according to the webpage characteristics.

Comment: In the Visual Basic IDE, hit F2 to open the Object Browser. Search for "WebElement", and see if that returns any definitions.

Comment: Yes it does. Many methods and properties are shown, but the thing is that I don't know what to pass to a method when it is expecting a WebElement. In my automation I declared the "driver" object as Selenium.webdriver and then I call methods of that object or sendkeys or click elements found by name, id, etc. But I don't know what I should send to the 'SwitchToFrame' method as a 'WebElement'.

Comment: I'm going to ask again, a complete code sample would be very helpful.

Comment: I tried to comment in reply to your request, kismert. But it didn't look well, so I edited the question. There you will find the steps that took me to the point of having to select an item on a menu that is inside two frames. One interesting thing I just noticed is that the line of HTML that defines the topFrameset, when inspected with Mozilla Firefox, shows like a small button on its right side which says "HTML", and if I hover on it it says "Events notification". Could this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Of course that when trying to click the menu item, my first try wasn't to switch to a frame, I just tried to click on the element which ID I got by inspecting the element with my browser. Once that didn't work, I tried to use another parameters (not ID). When that didn't work, I researched and found out that someone recommended to switch to the frame where the element is contained. So I am trying to do that since that moment, putting the name inside double quotes. The JAVA examples I found didn't help me because i guess JAVA has more methods available.

Answer (score 0):

After working a lot with this, I found the solution by myself.
I installed the app "SideeX" available at the Google Store. I then recorded the actions I needed to emulate with Selenium.
Then, I noticed that the frames whose names I described in the original question (topFrameset, BodyFrameset, ButtonsFrame) where recorded by SideeX through their indexes.
So I just had to perform the same actions with Selenium. In my case, for example, I had the following sequence of actions:

```
driver.SwitchToFrame 0
driver.SwitchToFrame 1
driver.FindElementById("img_501").Click
driver.SwitchToParentFrame
driver.SwitchToFrame 2
```

This is just my case, but the important thing that can be helpful for others with the same problem is to know that you can use SideeX to help you find the indexes of elements or sequence of actions needed to achieve your goal.

Comment: https://sideex.io/