# Using VBA SeleniumBasic, how can I define the HTML source within a frame in a similar way to the Microsoft HTML Object Library?

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Since Internet Explorer was completely disabled, a lot of VBA code I had written involving webscraping has become completely useless, and that required using Microsoft Internet Controls along with Microsoft HTML Object Library in VBA.

An issue I'm immediately running into is with a web page for gathering statistics. The web page is split into two separate frames that each stores an HTML document. The first one has various buttons and dropdowns I need to interact with, the second also has some options as well as the main table that is displayed from the options in the first frame.

My goal is to navigate between both frames instantly without having to use the "SwitchToFrame" method, as fundamentally I want the Selenium web driver (in my specific case, using Chrome) to keep the entire page in mind and be able to reference information from both frames in tandem.

This was easily possible with the Microsoft HTML Object Library; my original code as simply as follows:

```
Set htmldoc = IE.Document
Set htmldoc2 = htmldoc.Frames(0).Document
Set htmldoc3 = htmldoc.Frames(1).Document
```

This allowed me to interact across the first and second frame on the page effortlessly simply be referring to the variable referring to that page. I want to do exactly the same overall process with Selenium but can't figure out how since the .PageSource method is only available for the browser driver itself and not for WebElement objects.

Presuming that it is somehow possible to accomplish it, how do I do this?

I've tried using a similar approach to the original above, such as follows:

```
Set GC = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
GC.Start
GC.Get website

Set htmldoc2 = GC.FindElementByName("querybar")
Set htmldoc3 = GC.FindElementByName("query_frame")
```

I've also tried using Microsoft HTML Object Library with Selenium, but it seems that Selenium does not work effectively with it. In this example:

```
Set GC = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
GC.Start
GC.Get "http://www.stats.indiana.edu/laus/laus_view3.html"

set htmldoc = new HTMLDocument
htmldoc.body.innerHTML = GC.PageSource
Set htmldoc2 = htmldoc.Frames(0).Document
Set htmldoc3 = htmldoc.Frames(1).Document
```

but from trying to work with it (unless I missed something or made an error when originally trying it), MSHTML controls do not update the Selenium browser or the displayed HTML.

Comment: Side note: Have you tried to extract innerHTML and outerHTML from any node referenced by a webElement using `.Attribute()`?

Comment: This post looks like it will help  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445717/how-can-i-click-a-button-inside-a-frame-with-selenium-webdriver-in-vba

Comment: @QHarr Unless I'm misunderstanding how to use it, .Attribute doesn't seem to return anything when setting the frames as the WebElements.

Comment: @user10186832 I've seen that page already which is why I made this post; I explicitly want to NOT use the SwitchToFrame method, and instead define the entire HTML contents within a frame as an object to reference and manipulate through the webdriver.

Comment: You call `.Attribute()` on the webElement and specify the attribute e.g. the inner or outer html inside the call `()`. That needs to be put somewhere e.g. into a string variable. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382559/6241235

Comment: I am not aware of what you want to do being possible with selenium basic and will be interested to see if you find a way. You were lucky, or unlucky, with what happens with `Set htmldoc = IE.Document`, where you still actually reference the IE DOM instance and changes are propagated. However, such practices can lead to stale element exceptions on previously set DOM object variables below the document level.